# Configure XDebug with NetBeans debug PHP code

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I have installed NetBeans on Windows XP machine. I have also downloaded XDebug but I am not sure how to configure to debug the remote server(development machine). My development server is windows 2008 server(64 bit). What version of XDebug do I have to use? My local machine is Windows XP. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug)?

Comment: I read this but still I am not clear about the changing the php.ini file. Where do I have to download XDebug?(server or local computer)

Comment: You have to setup xDebug on the server

Answer (score -1):

I know it's far to late. But maybe the answer is helpful to someone passing by the post.

You can find customized installation steps [here](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php). The link provided is a reference to a page in which you paste in your php info. The page prints a list of steps to setup xdebug on your machine.

If the link is dead at the time of reading this post, please search using the keywords "xdebug tailored installation steps". This should take you directly to the page in question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21583315)

Comment: Updated my answer with as much verbosity as I could in regards to the link provided. Thanks for pointing this out.